# How to map a NSArray with NSStrings in the request (RESTKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, restkit, restkit-0.20

I got a problem with a request mapping in Restkit 0.20. I want to put a NSArray with NSStrings into the request under the the key "mails" e.g.:

```
{mails:[@"first@gmail.com",@"second@gmail.com"]}
```

So, for this case I don't really need an object mapping, cause I am using only standard objects. I just didn't get it to work, so I switched back to the regular way (at least for me) - introducing a DTO object MailRequest which contains the NSArray. I do it like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping =  [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"mails":@"mails"
}];  

RKRequestDescriptor *reqDesc = 
            [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                  objectClass:[MailRequest class]
                                                  rootKeyPath:nil];

RKObjectManager *manager = ...
...
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager requestWithObject:requestObject 
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodPOST 
                                                     path:urlString parameters:nil];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = 
                     [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request ...
```

... but I would like to get rid of the MailsRequest DTO object. Is that possible?

Comment: If you have an object that has an array relationship to some other object which has the string as a property it should be. Show the data structure where the strings are stored.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use an object (like MailsRequest) as I did in my example. Instead I wanna put the array directly into the request.

Comment: So why not just create the JSON and NSURLRequest yourself (with the JSON data), then pass to RKObjectRequestOperation ?

Comment: Sounds good, do you have a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the mapping step and just use RestKit for the send and any response mapping. Build your dictionary any way you want. You do need to create the URL from `urlString`.

```
NSDictionary *mails = @{mails:@[@"first@gmail.com",@"second@gmail.com"]};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *mailsJSON = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mails options:0 error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:mailsJSON];

RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request ...
```